# Why use a database path in c# when we also use one in web.config?

Tags: asp.net

Why use a database path in c# when we also use one in web.config?

for example:

I use in web.config and c#.net:

```
string connetionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=pubs;User ID=sa;Password=*****"
```

Why use the same string in c#.net that we also used in web.config file?

Comment: The connection string in your web configuration files shall be used in your C#.

Answer (score 1):

In your Web.Config, you should have something like this:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" 
        connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

In your aspx.cs pages, you should have something like this:

```
    string str = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
```

Then, when you go to open a connection, you do something like:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str))
```

That is how you properly set up your connection strings.